# Monitor HDMI and CPU Displayport and performance

Tags: vga, displayport

I have a desktop that has two DisplayPorts. However my monitor accepts only HDMI and VGA input. How can I connect the DisplayPort 1.2 output to my monitor?

I plan to use multiple monitors in the future. Will it make an impact in the long run if I choose display port over VGA ?

Comment: It's called "DisplayPort" without a space. Used in a sentence: "I have a desktop that has two DisplayPort connectors." Also, a "CPU" is the chip inside the case, not the case itself.

Answer (score 1):

You buy a [display port to HDMI adapter](http://ca.startech.com/AV/Displayport-Converters/DisplayPort-to-HDMI-Adapter-Converter-Cable~DP2HDMI), and then connect to the monitor using HDMI cable.

I believe the best resolution VGA will give you is 720p, and with HDMI through display port you get full HD resolution (1080p).

Comment: VGA in itself doesn't have a limit. However, most graphic cards will limit it to 2048x1536 (because of the DAC bandwith). That say, a monitor with a resolution greater than 1920x1200 and only a VGA connector is very rare (though 22" at 1920x1080 are somewhat common).
With the latest version of HDMI (so a compatible graphic card and adapter), it's possible to drive a 4096×2160 monitor.

Comment: I have Intel Integrated HD 4600. http://www.intel.in/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/guides/performance-xeon-e3-1200-hd-graphics-p4000-guide.pdf. it does say that VGA support some higher resoultion.Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

As Dallas said, you can connect your monitor to DisplayPort with the help of a DP-HDMI adapter. Be sure to get a good-quality one (and supporting DP 1.2) since otherwise you wouldn't be able to get high resolution and long cable distance support.

Some advantages are listed here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Advantages_over_DVI.2C_VGA_and_FPD-Link but those are probably not what you might be interested in.
The main advantage over VGA is that the signal is digital, not analog : interferences and low-quality cables will not produce "noise" on the image. It also helps getting higher resolution on longer distances without quality loss. Another fact is the DRM support.